# Swift CollectionViewCell Auto Height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I try to make my cell to auto resize with the content of a label.
My Cell contains two labels. The first label is always one line, the other can be multiline.
The problem is that the cell won't resize. This is my code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    CollectionViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(60 + 60 * commentaires.count)
    return commentaires.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = commentCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.contentCommentLabel.text = commentaires[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameCommentLabel.text = commentairesNom[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // This is Just for example , for the scenario Step-I -> 1
    let yourWidthOfLable = self.view.bounds.size.width
    let font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 14.0)

    var expectedHeight = heightForLable(text: commentaires[indexPath.row], font: font!, width:yourWidthOfLable )

    print("expectedHeight : " + String(describing: expectedHeight))
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: expectedHeight)
}

func heightForLable(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}
```

Comment: If `collectionView: collectionViewLayout` method is called? Please, post your code for `heightForLable ` method

Comment: head over to https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

Comment: I've just tried, the function `collectionView: collectionViewLayout`isn't called, I don't know why

Comment: `heightForLable` code added

Comment: @UmarFarooque it seems to be this but I can't manage to make it works

Answer (score 0):

Usually i use this code to configure my CollectionView:

```
    private func config_collection()
    {
        self.collection_view.delegate = self
        self.collection_view.dataSource = self
        self.collection_view.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        self.collection_view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collection_view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        self.collection_view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        if let layout = self.collection_view.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        {
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                            sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Edit 1:
To resize the cell by estimate height i use this code:

```
func get_size_height_text(texto: String,
                              ui_view: UIView) -> CGFloat
    {
        let l : [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
        let size = CGSize(width: ui_view.frame.width,
                          height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimateFrame = NSString(string: texto).boundingRect(with: size,
                                                                 options: options,
                                                                 attributes: l,
                                                                 context: nil)
        return estimateFrame.height
    }
```

To use it, run this code:

```
let height = get_size_height_text(texto: label.text ?? "",
                               ui_view: self.view)
```

with this height, you need to increment the value with your preference to use it in your cell

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work, the UICollectionView height is always 50

Comment: It's just an example, the width and height needs to get other configuration

Comment: It doesn't work, the cell is always the same height whatever height value, the function seems to never get called

Comment: I found why the function never get called, it was because I didn't added UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to my class, now I'll try to adjust cell's height, thanks

Comment: It's very important to add this delegate to handle the size of cell :D good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to get height of UILabel programmatically according to font family, font size and width of UILabel and than after add this height in top UILabel's height. This is your total height of cell.

Comment: Okay but where in the file should I define the cell Height ?

Comment: Create a common function which get text of second Label and return total height of cell. Call this function in sizeOfItem function(where we set height and width of cell).

Comment: Yes but this function seems to never get called

Comment: pls let me know why this function not get call

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: create class function in Cell class.

Comment: I found why the function never get called, it was because I didn't added UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to my class, now I'll try to adjust cell's height, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165905/discussion-between-hitesh-agarwal-and-erwann-bestard).